# $K$-theory and surjective norm-decreasing $*$-homomorphisms between $C^*$-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $C^*$-algebras, and let $p:A \to B$ be a surjective norm-decreasing $*$-homomorphism which is injective on a dense $*$-sub-algebra of $A$. Can such a map have non-trivial kernel, and if so, is it possible that the $K$-theory groups of $A$ and $B$ can be non-isomorphic?

Comment: All star-HMs between Cstar algebras are automatically norm-decreasing (assuming you mean what I would call contractive)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes to both.$\newcommand{\Cst}{{\rm C}^*}$
 The standard example for the first is: take a discrete group $G$ and let $A$ be its full $\Cst$-algebra, $B$ its reduced $\Cst$-algebra. There is a canonical homomorphism $q:A\to B$ which is injective when restricted to $\ell^1(G)$; but $q$ is injective if and only if $G$ is amenable. So any non-amenable discrete group will provides examples for your first question.

There are non-amenable groups $G$ for which $q$ induces an isomorphism on $K$-theory — I think the standard name for such groups is $K$-amenable. Lance proved that free groups have this property. But infinite groups with Kazhdan's Property (T) do not have this property because the so-called Kazhdan projection in the full group $\Cst$-algebra lies in the kernel of $q$. (Thanks to Jamie Gabe in comments for clarifying/sharpening my original statement.)

(See also this MO question [$*$-algebras, completions, and $K$-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315907/algebras-completions-and-k-theory) )

Comment: It might be worth adding that the Kazhdan projection $p$ has non-trivial $K_0$-class in the kernel of $q$ since $p$ is mapped to a generating projection in $K_0(\mathbb C) = \mathbb Z$ by the trivial representation.

Answer (score 8):

There are even commutative counterexamples. Let $A = C[0,2]$ and let $A_0$ be the $*$-subalgebra of all polynomials in $x$. Then let $p: C[0,2] \to C[0,1]$ be the restriction map.

(My first example took $A = C[0,3]$ and let $A_0$ be the set of all polynomials in $x$ with rational coefficients and $p: A \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ the point evaluation at $x = e$. Since $e$ is transcendental, $p$ is injective on $A_0$. But $A_0$ is not a $*$-subalgebra over $\mathbb{C}$.)